# electron.exe and Github

Tags: github, electron, large-files

I have a repository/program that requires Electron. GitHub doesn't allow adding files larger than 100MB, however, the `electron.exe` file in the Electron node module is 105MB so I can't figure out how to add it into my repo. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is not required. Because Git is needed for management source code. Electron.exe and node modules can be processed by package.json.
So if you add package.json includes electron and other information, you can use easily later.